# How to combine to generic lists with add range and select criteria?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

How to combine to generic lists with add range and select criteria? Here is a fictitious example. I can addRange but not with filtering on a criteria like room type. The "Select(mr => mr.Type == RoomType.BedRoom)" does not work. What can I use instead to just append the list where type = BedRoom?

```
public enum RoomType
{
    Bathroom = 1,
    BedRoom = 2,
    Kitchen = 3,
    RecRoom = 4
}

public class RoomsModel
{
    public RoomType Type { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
}

public List<RoomsModel> GetRooms(params)
{
    var result = new List<RoomsModel>();

    result = _service.GetRooms(house1);

    var moreRooms _service.GetRooms(house2);

    result.AddRange((from mr in moreRooms
                 select new RoomsModel
                 {
                     Type = mr.Type,
                     Size = mr.Size
                 }
                 ).Select(mr => mr.Type == RoomType.BedRoom).ToList());

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Where` instead of `Select`:

```
result.AddRange(
  from mr in moreRooms
  where mr.Type == RoomType.BedRoom
  select new RoomsModel
  {
    Type = mr.Type,
    Size = mr.Size
  });
```

`Where` filters items. `Select` projects item, i.e. transforms each item in the sequence into something else.

Comment: I beat you to it by a small bit, but +1 for using 100% LINQ for the job. Wasn't really sure if LINQ had `where` clauses

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Where` instead of `Select`:

```cs
result.AddRange((from mr in moreRooms
                 select new RoomsModel
                 {
                     Type = mr.Type,
                     Size = mr.Size
                 }
                 ).Where(mr => mr.Type == RoomType.BedRoom).ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

one more way:

```
 result.AddRange(moreRooms.Where(mr => mr.Type == RoomType.BedRoom)
   .Select(mr => new RoomsModel {
     Type = mr.Type, 
     Size = mr.Size
   }));
```